# HTTP header names in Go

Tags: http, go

I need to collect a bunch of http headers. The only way I found yet is *http.Request `.Header.Get("%header name%")`
Is there any name conventions for %header name% ? 
**E.g.** in PHP all keys are uppercased, words separated with underscore.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a set of sample HTTP headers that you've been using as test cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys in a header are in [canonical format](http://godoc.org/net/http#CanonicalHeaderKey).

The [Header](http://godoc.org/net/http#Header) methods canonicalize the the key for you.

If the application accesses the header map directly, then the application is responsible for ensuring that the key is in canonical format.

Some examples of header names in canonical format are:

```
Content-Length
Etag
```

You can find all headers using range:

```
for name, values := range req.Header {
     fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", name, values)
}
```